# Particle system puts everything on a circle around object ? Tried with Geometry nodes too, the same

Tags: system

New to blender I try modeling a tick .. I'm about to put hait on the body but it doesn't work.. when I add a partcile system (or geometry nodes) everything is added on a circle around the object.. here's the link to the file.. : https://pasteall.org/media/f/8/f855c53839b7736296afd8b4775acd7b.blend

Any ideas ?

Comment: Hello and welcome. please add more than just the Blend file. Screenshots of your object, your settings and so. The more info, the better to answerd the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hair object is far from its origin on the X axis, that will shift the hair away from the emitting faces on their Y axis (I still don't know why hair's X axis becomes Y on the emitter though). If you move the hair object in *Edit* mode towards its origin it will shift back:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it actually helped me to find the origin of the problem, no pun intended, since the object's origin was off center.. just had to align origin to geometry and that did it !